# PHP Baseball Code: Reducing number of digits

Tags: php

new to this site and some of the PHP basics. For this code, I'm looking to reduce the digits of the batting average down to three digits. If you look at the code in a web page, it has 12 digits, ex: 0.189189189189.

How would I reduce the digits to 3 instead of 12? It'll better showcast my horrible batting average.

Here is:

```
<?php

$full_name = "Robbee Thomas";
$position = "SS";
$bathand = "R";
$throwhand = "R";

$hits = 35;
$atbats = 185;
$batavg = $hits / $atbats

?>
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $full_name ?></h1>

<p>Position:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $position ?></p>
<p>Bat:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $bathand ?></p>
<p>Throw:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $throwhand ?></p>
<p>Batting Avg:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $batavg ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the number_format function to round up to the desired decimal places.

Change

```
<?php echo $batavg ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo number_format((float)$batavg, 3, '.', '') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a billion, it worked. Sorry it took me 25 years (or 2 weeks) to reply.